# insert web page (like ticket booking) into another page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, iframe

i need to integrate http://www.ebookers.com/ booking system into my web page, unfortunately i've never done that before.

Would be glad to hear any advice how to accomplish this.

Thank You !

Comment: Why are you needing to integrate with the website? Just asking from a "I'd like to have it as part of my site" or "I'm a partner with them" type of scenario. If partner route (or other) you should enquire as to whether they have a control you can load in, or an api you can integrate with. An iFrame loading their site in yours could lead to a security risk if asking for credit card details etc.

Comment: hi. thx for reply. jep, i just realized that the way to make this is to use deep linking.

Comment: they use Querystring for search. copy the html of them and make them work using their querystring. means redirect to a page with Querystring and they will worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

<

```
html>
<head>

<title>iframe</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>

this is my part of the page

</div>

<iframe src="http://www.google.com">abcd</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

u can give whatever url in src field of iframe